# Background-size like value for an image in a full width div

Tags: html, css

When using a full width background image you are able to set the background-size:cover. To make the image fit the screen without losing the quality of the image.

Is there a similar solution for an image?

I am using an image in a full screen div (max height:500px) but when applying the full width to the image the image height is much higher (+1000px) so is there a solution to let this image fit perfectly in the 100% width div with a max height of 500px?

I am now using margin-bottom:-20% but then the image resolution is crap and zoomed in way to much.

```
.node-type-article .group-header{
    margin: 0 -100% 50px -100%;
    max-height: 500px;
}
.node-type-article .group-header img{
    margin-bottom: -20%;
}
.node-type-article .l-main{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

So any suggestions? Scaling, resizing,...?

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;`?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please?

Comment: you can set the size of the img in the path after the src - width="auto" height = "500" e.g.

Comment: have you tried - `img { max-height: 500px; width: 100% }` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this solution the image fits in the 100% width and is cropped to 500px height:

> ```
> .node-type-article{
>     width: 100%;
>
> }
> .node-type-article .group-header{
>     width: 100%;
>     max-height: 500px;
>     overflow: hidden;
> }
> .node-type-article .group-header img{
>     width: 100%;
>
> }
> ```
>
> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7m9ddvo8/)

Or with this solution the image is also 100% width but it's height is stretched/shrinked to 500px:

> ```
> .node-type-article{
>     width: 100%;
>
> }
> .node-type-article .group-header{
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 500px;
>     overflow: hidden;
> }
> .node-type-article .group-header img{
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 100%;
> }
> ```
>
> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryw3pqrs/1/)

Or check this pen: http://codepen.io/ErwanHesry/pen/JcvCw